# When the reference to an object is created in Java?

Tags: java, constructor

```
class myClass{
    public myClass(){
        // INITIALIZATION
    }
    ...
}
...
myClass a;
...
a = new myClass();
```

When does the reference to object *a* stop being `null`?
As soon as the constructor is invoked or when it completes?

Comment: After the assignment expression finishes. That's necessarily after `new myClass()` has finished.

Comment: when the constructor returns successfully

Comment: From the point of view of this thread, it's after construction has finished.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what are you trying to do that requires you to know?

Comment: Can be argueable due to double check locking

Comment: @AndyTurner my question has reasons to exists otherwise I wouldn't ask at all. Btw, feel free to not answer

Comment: @Luigi2405 you might get a more useful answer if you share those reasons :)

Comment: @Antoniossss that's right

Comment: In a sense `a` is never `null` (assuming it's a local variable). The Java compiler (together with the bytecode verifier) makes sure that you can never read the content of a local variable that hasn't had a value written to it, so the very first value you write to a local variable in your code is the first value it has. It's not "null" before, it simply doesn't have a value that you can read.

Comment: @AndyTurner in double-check singleton pattern in a multithread environment, each thread that wants the (hopefully) unique instance of ``myClass`` must preventively check if _a_ is null, but if a thread already started a (time-consuming) constructor and if what you answered is not true, then a new thread requesting for the instance would find a not null and the object that it is returned is in an inconsistent state since it's being created at that very time

Comment: Ah, so you're asking about multi-threading. In that case, the assignment can happen at any time provided it's not observably different from the program order in the current thread. In other words: don't rely on it happening at any time without appropriate synchronization.

Comment: @AndyTurner maybe you miss my last comment. In any case thanks for answering.

Of course, I don't want to use `volatile` modifier and when a thread invokes the constructur this is done in mutually exclusion fashion and with double-check, obviously

Comment: @Luigi2405 so if you are asking in context of double check locking, than it is 1) XY question 2) it is answered planty of times.

Comment: @Antoniossss 3) I had really that doubt and I didn't find any satisfactory answer.

Comment: You just asked the wrong question.Try this one http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Answer (score 1):

In the line `a = new myClass();` several things are happening:

1. `new myClass();` creates an instance of the new object. `a` would still be `null` at this point. Strictly speaking, it is not even a `null`, it is `not initialized` state.
2. Assignment operator `=` assigns `a` a new value, which is a link to the object, created in step 1

So `a` has proper value only after the assignment is completed.

If you have a look at the bytecode, you can see that the actual assignment happens on line 13.
Bytecode:

```
Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: new           #2                  // class a$MyClass
       7: dup
       8: aload_0
       9: aconst_null
      10: invokespecial #3                  // Method a$MyClass."<init>":(La;La$1;)V
      13: astore_1
      14: return
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `a` variable in separate line is just a syntactic sugar and has no effect on the bytecode. The `javac` compiler will process your code the same way as `myClass a = new myClass();`.

Consider following example, added `System.out` as an example code:

```
myClass a;
System.out.println("b");
a = new myClass();
```

which produces following bytecode (`javap -v Main.class`):

```
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: getstatic     #7                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
         3: ldc           #13                 // String b
         5: invokevirtual #15                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
         8: new           #21                 // class myClass
        11: dup
        12: invokespecial #23                 // Method myClass."<init>":()V
        15: astore_1
        16: return
```

where `System.out` was executed before `a` was ever processed.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this by using a `static` field to print out the value of the Object during the construction.

```
class Test {    
    public static Test t;
    
    public Test() {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        t = new Test();
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> null
>
> test.Test@7852e922

The output shows `null` from the `print` inside the constructor, because the `static` object `t` has not been assigned yet, but after completion of `t = new Test()` it appears that `t` has now been assigned.

Comment: That's for class fields that have default value. A regular variable within method body doesn't.

Comment: @Karol Dowbecki I am aware the field will have a default value, this is just to show that `t` will not be assigned until after `new Test()` is completed, I do not mean to imply the initial value of `t` will always be `null`.